# I can´t remove the last item of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can remove any item of array unless the last one. I also use angularjs to show information in the view. I don´t know what is happening with the last item of this array. Please, anyone can help me?

**Here is HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4><strong>Documento {{index + 1}} de {{documentos.length}}:</strong> {{documentos[index].nome}}</h4>
                <iframe style="background: #ccc;" ng-show="exibirPreview" frameborder="0" ng-src="{{versaoLink}}" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>
                <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-hide="exibirPreview">
                    @Html.Raw(Resources.Dialog.SignDocuments.TypeDocumentCanNotPreDisplayed)
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="pull-right btn-row" ng-show="documentos.length > 1">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="RemoveDoc(index)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i> @Resources.Common.RemoveDocList</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Here is js/angularjs**

```
 $scope.documentos = [
    {nome:"document1", chave: "8F65579E3737706F", extensao:".pdf"},
    {nome:"document2", chave: "8F65579E3730007F", extensao:".pdf"},
    {nome:"document3", chave: "8545579E3737706F", extensao:".pdf"},
    {nome:"document4", chave: "8555579E3730007F", extensao:".pdf"}
]

$scope.ViewLink = function () {
                var versao = $scope.documentos[$scope.index];
                $scope.exibirPreview = versao.extensao == ".pdf" || versao.extensao == ".txt";
                if (!$scope.exibirPreview) {
                    $scope.versaoLink = '';
                } else {
                    $scope.versaoLink = '/Documento/VersaoView?chave=' + versao.chave;
                }
            };
        $scope.ViewLink();

        $scope.RemoveDoc = function (index) {
            $scope.documentos.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.ViewLink();
        };
```

Or [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tploSeguyrGjg9aAkTtg)

Comment: `splice` starts with 0, not 1.

Comment: `$scope.documentos` have only one object

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML you are preventing the deletion of the last element:

```
<div class="pull-right btn-row" ng-show="documentos.length > 1">
   <!-- -->
</div>
```

`documentos.length > 1` means "hide when it reaches one item in the array".

It should be `documentos.length == 0`.

It's either this or your `index` value starts from 1 and not from 0.

Comment: I tried but did not remove any items. Look at this:
$scope.RemoveDoc = function (index) {
                $scope.documentos.splice(index, 0);
                $scope.ViewLink();
            };

Comment: splice(index, 1) is the correct way, but I was asking about the value of `index` what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to change your remove function to take in the document instead of the index. Try this:

```
$scope.RemoveDoc = function(document) { 
  var index = $scope.documents.indexOf(document);
  $scope.documents.splice(index, 1);     
}
```

in view:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="RemoveDoc(document)">Delete</button>
```

Comment: It worked, but the view is not acting the right way. The H4 tag does not bring any information when I remove the last item.

Comment: Use $index in place of index. And let me know if it works